# How to filter apps from installed apps on device programmatically

Tags: android, google-play

I want to filter application from installed apps in my device. My Question is:

Is it possible to filter which is game apps, which is music apps and which is business apps from all installed apps?  If the answer is yes, please provide some methods or tutorial.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

The PackageManager class is a Class for retrieving various kinds of information related to the application packages that are currently installed on a device.

You can access to a specific ApplicationInfo from the PackageManager.

ApplicationInfo is information you can retrieve about a particular application. This corresponds to information collected from the AndroidManifest.xml's  tag

Unfortunately, there is no information about the type of application (if it is a game or a music app for example).

Comment: Thanks Renaud,but in google play store we saw that they are categorize in same way what i want....

Comment: Yes but Android Play Store and Android are two different things. You could parse Android Play Store with the list of your installed app (using the PackageManager) then filter them.

Answer (score -1):

Ya i got the answer for this using jsoup library i access the categeory from play store only..

```
   try {                
            Document doc = Jsoup.connect("https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=url").get();
            String title = doc.title();
            System.out.println("title : " + title);             
            Elements links = doc.select("p");               
            System.out.println("text : " + links.text());               

        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```